# Wireless Adapter TCP Retransmissions

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark

I'm on OSX High Sierra 10.13.4 and like to work from the park where there are wireless hotspots.  My laptop's wireless can connect to these networks but the connection drops occasionally.

I recently purchased this TrendNet TEW-809UB usb wireless adapter [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01EOQ61KI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EOQ61KI) to fix the occasional drops.  This wireless adapter is able to connect to the hotspots but can't connect to the internet or ping 8.8.8.8.  It's able to connect to the internet on my home router at 2.4 and 5 GHz.

I ran Wireshark and there are a lot of TCP Retransmissions. I don't have these when connected with my built-in wireless adapter. Here's an image of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khk5a.jpg

Here's the full wireshark: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hBaP7KzTHWB33WqVQqalwkM2na0uuPvU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your issue seems to be shared by a large community of folks who have purchased the same adapter.  https://www.amazon.com/Trendnet-AC1900-Wireless-Adapter-TEW-809UB/product-reviews/B01EOQ61KI/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewopt_kywd?pageNumber=1&filterByKeyword=Mac

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping it'd work as some have said it works on High Sierra.  It was able to connect to my local network just not the long-range ones.  I was hoping there was some kind of configuration that could be changed to resolve the issue.  Oh well, I went ahead and return it :)

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and returned the adapter as Trendnet support said OSX High Sierra 10.13.4 isn't officially supported